# How to approach controlling multiple sets of solenoid valves?

Tags: design, diy, 24v

Please excuse me for asking basic questions as I am a newbie in this field and learning as I go.

I have a project that requires simultaneous functioning of two solenoid valves. I require three sets of two solenoids. Set when one is energized it needs to open two valves and so forth.

Each set needs to be energized for a period of one hour. I have six Burkert 6281-EV-A13 - 24V - 8W Normally-closed solenoid valves. The valves will be used to control the flow of air from a vacuum pump.

I have researched quite a bit but it seems there is a lot of different ways to go about the circuit design and I have no clue which would be the best route to take. In essence, all I need to do is switch the solenoid on and off via an on/off switch or remote receiver. No PLC or signal controls are required. Any assistance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The answers below cover the electrical aspects well, but I’d like to point out one pitfall of mixing electronics and fluid controls: “open” and “closed” mean opposite things. A closed electrical circuit allows for the flow of electrons, a closed valve does not permit the flow of air.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Are you asking about a circuit or device that turns on each solenoid pair for one hour in succession, or about manually switching each pair?

Comment: @Bryan thanks for that as i understand it. If the valves are "normally closed" that means they will restrict air flow whereas the electronics "normally closed" will be allowing current to flow through. "Normally open" on the valves will let the air flow through and electronics will be restricting the current.

Comment: @AnalogKid thanks basically both :-) In terms of the switching it can be manually or automatic. Whichever is better for safety and longevity of the valves

Answer (score 1):

Solenoid valves are basically exactly what they sound like: a solenoid which, when energised, operates a valve. (Here's a good video from [Engineering Mindset](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-MLGr1_Fw0c) explaining them.)

You have 24VDC solenoids, so you can do it as simply as this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdIV01.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- **Power**: As the valves are 8W, you'd expect them to need 8 / 24 = 0.3A each, so you'll need a decent kind of power supply.
- **Timer** If you want to control that hour automatically, you'll want some kind of timer.  (But you'll need to update your question with details of how it knows when to go on, how long exactly to stay on, etc.)
- **Long cable** If the cable is long, it's better to replace the switch with a relay, so that the higher current is local to the solenoids.  (But you'd need to update your question with details of length to answer this.)
- **Safety** It can get a lot more complicated if there's anything dangerous involved, or risks associated with one valve failing, that you need to take into account.  The above is the basic starting point.

Comment: thanks a lot for the response. Power: I was thinking of a 24V - 3A power supply.

Comment: Timer: It would be ideal to be automated however if it's as simple as the diagram you provided then can do so manually. Would it not need a flyback diode though. Long cable: The 1st set will be about 5m from a possible power source and the 2nd set will be appr. 75m away. The 2 valves needing to work together are 75m apart. Safety: I don't foresee any dangers as I understand a failure will result in the valve closing which will then just be flagged at the vacuum pump. If the vlave remains open then that would be a different story

Answer (score 0):

Here's the schematic.

[image]

Y1 - Y6 are the solenoid valves.

S1 - S3 are SPST switches or RF remote controlled switches.

D1 - D3 are the flyback diodes.

With the coil consumption being 48 W, the current drawn at 24 V would be 2 A.

A 24 V DC - 3 A power supply unit would suffice.

Comment: Thanks a lot: that helps knowing that no driver or arduino or anything like that is needed

Comment: Anytime, Jacques Le Roux.